# How can I get in 'clicked' element in jquery ajax success callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is one easy (I hope) question which is bugging me for years. 
How do you get element that fired event which triggered the ajax request?
Here is an example:

```
<button id="clickme">Click me</button>
$("#clickme").click(function(e){
    var i_need_this=e.target;
    alert(i_need_this); //nice!
    $.ajax({
            url:'http://echo.jsontest.com/',

            type: 'GET',
            success: function( data, status, jqXHR  ) {
                alert('success');
              //console.log( ??? ); Get i_need_this from somewhere?       
            }
        });

})
```

Live: http://jsfiddle.net/8F3u2/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try this?  `console.log( i_need_this);`

Comment: @Praveen I think there is no such variable as e inside success callback; *UPD* Wow, it seems I was wrong and you where right! Sorry. Still messing with scope in js.

Comment: @Anton I tried this. Well, what can I say - both yours and Praveen's methods works. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `context` param here:

```
$.ajax({
        url:'http://echo.jsontest.com/',
        context:this, // <------this is the cliked button
        type: 'GET',
```

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly it. I kinda feel stupid, it was in docs.